# How to add Ubuntu GNOME terminal in Docky launcher?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, dock, docky

After upgrading Ubuntu I can't pin GNOME Terminal in Docky launcher.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Open a terminal and go to the `~/.local/share/applications` directory:

   ```
   cd ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Create a file there named `gnome-terminal.desktop`:

   ```
   nano gnome-terminal.desktop
   ```
3. Copy and paste the following inside that file:

   ```bsh
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Terminal
   Comment=ubuntu termial
   Exec=gnome-terminal
   Icon=terminal
   Type=Application
   ```
4. Save and close it.
5. Then open the terminal again and <kbd>right-click</kbd> on its icon on Docky. You should be able to see a *Pin to Dock* option.